# Not navigating to Child Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have defined the routes as follows. However, when I try to navigate to the `/user/school/` path I don't see the view (I just see a blank webpage). My HTML code is as follows. Can someone help please.

HTML

```
 <a  href ="/user/school" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button"  >
    School
 </a>
```

Route

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  {path:"user" , component:DbComponent, canActivate:[AcGuardService], data : {expectedRole:"admin"},
    children: [
      {path:"school" , component:CCComponent, canActivate:[AcGuardService], data : {expectedRole:"admin"}},

    ]
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not have written the route exit
Please check whether 'dbComponent' and 'ccComponent' provide ''

Comment: Sorry but I did not get what you said

Comment: Please check whether 'dbComponent' and 'ccComponent' provide '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'

Comment: Give me some recognition

Answer (score 0):

try to use `routerLink="/user/school"` (not **href**)

Comment: It doesn't even navigate :(

Comment: when add your layout component html file (where u render DbComponent with router-outlet) and dbComponent html file